# Why is it error when converting more than 3 billions to an integer

Tags: android, kotlin

I know some countries use commas as thousands separator, but in the other countries, they use dots, for instance 1.000.000.000. So my task is to convert string number with these dots from EditTextInput to integer in Kotlin.

I use the following formula:

```js
EditTextInteger = Integer.parseInt(edit_text_input.text.toString().replace(Regex("[.]"),""))
```

The code seems fine for thousands (1.000), millions (1.000.000), and up to 2 billions (2.000.000.000) but after 3 billions (3.000.000.000), the following error appears:

```js
Process: com.example.gesit, PID: 10157
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3000000000"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:747)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:865)
        at com.example.gesit.TambahProduk$onCreate$4.onTextChanged(TambahProduk.kt:262)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:11888)
        at android.widget.TextView.handleTextChanged(TextView.java:12018)
        at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.onTextChanged(TextView.java:15206)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1278)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:587)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:314)
        at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:518)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:304)
        at androidx.emoji2.text.SpannableBuilder.replace(SpannableBuilder.java:48)
        at android.text.method.NumberKeyListener.onKeyDown(NumberKeyListener.java:129)
        at android.widget.TextView.doKeyDown(TextView.java:9533)
        at android.widget.TextView.onKeyDown(TextView.java:9305)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3664)
        at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:14927)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1991)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1991)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1991)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1991)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.dispatchKeyEvent(ScrollView.java:738)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1991)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1991)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1991)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1991)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1991)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:1004)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1952)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:4225)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.superDispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:122)
        at androidx.core.view.KeyEventDispatcher.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEventDispatcher.java:84)
        at androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(ComponentActivity.java:140)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:599)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:3090)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(DecorView.java:823)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:7722)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:7545)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6922)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6979)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6945)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:7143)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6953)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:7200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6926)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:6979)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:6945)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:6953)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:6926)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10400)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:10248)
2022-08-18 19:38:22.931 10157-10157/com.example.gesit E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:10204)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessageImpl(ViewRootImpl.java:6539)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:6403)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
2022-08-18 19:38:22.977 10157-10157/com.example.gesit I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10157 SIG: 9
```

Why is that? and what need to be fixed?

Comment: Use `Long` or `BigInteger` .. you are parsing a value from EditText so there has to be a Max char limit set on your `EditText` .. Otherwise anything can overflow with parsing ..

Comment: @ADM yep, using Long fix this. Thanks